# How do i parse this specific html body using selector in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a specific item from a particular website.

The Code snippet is as follows:

```
    # Constant Div Path variables for Parameters.
    pathForMovieCardContainer = '//div[@class="card-container wow fadeIn movie-card-container"]'
    pathForMovieName = 'div[@class="card-container wow fadeIn movie-card-container"]//div[@class="cards"]//div[@class="card-details"]//div[@class="card-right"]//div[@class="card-title"]/text()'
    str_slash = "/"
    movies_dict = []
    movies = response.xpath(pathForMovieCardContainer).extract()

    for movie in movies:
        print("***********************")
        print(movie)
        mov = TestDataCrawlersItem()
        mov['name'] = Selector(text=movie).xpath(pathForMovieName).extract()
```

I am unable to get the text from the path `'div[@class="card-container wow fadeIn movie-card-container"]//div[@class="cards"]//div[@class="card-details"]//div[@class="card-right"]//div[@class="card-title"]/text()'` I am not sure if my `pathForMovieName` is constructed properly. Can some one help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Please specify the website you are trying to scrape

Comment: I am trying to scrape the latest available movies from https://in.bookmyshow.com/chennai/movies

Comment: Consider marking the answer as “accepted” :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to select a element by its class name, it is simpler to use `.css()` than `.xpath()`. You could try something like this:

```
movies = response.css('.movie-card-container')
for movie in movies:
    item = TestDataCrawlersItem()
    item['name'] = movie.css('.card-title::text').get()
```

More info about CSS selectors: https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html